# How can I pop up messages that rely on background task logic?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, task

Right now I have something like the following below:

```
private void DoSomethingAsync() {

    ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { PerformCDDetection(); }).ContinueWith(t => { ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed; });
}



 public ICommand ImportFilePathCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() => { DoSomethingAsync(); });
    }

}
  private void PerformCDDetection()
{
    //Gets all the drives 
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    //checks if any CD-Rom exists in the drives
    var cdRomExists = allDrives.Any(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom);

    // Get all the cd roms
    var cdRoms = allDrives.Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom && allDrives.Any(y => y.IsReady));

    if (cdRomExists.Equals(true))
    {
        // Loop through the cd roms collection
        foreach(var cdRom in cdRoms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", cdRom.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", cdRom.DriveType);

            if (cdRom.IsReady == true)
            {
                if (cdRom.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(cdRom.RootDirectory.Name);

                    var file = di.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("failed to find file"); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo info in di.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        {
                            Debug.Print(info.FullName);
                            break;      // only looking for the first one
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (cdRom.IsReady == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cd-ROM is not ready");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CD ROM is not detected");

    }

}
```

The Console.WriteLine statements should be dialogWindows/Message Boxes that pop up alerting the user about the conditions listed.

I removed the messages and substituted it with Console.WriteLine statements because I cannot run the messagebox.show() on the background task (It should be part of the UI thread not background).

I was wondering since the messages are displayed based on logic being performed in the background, how can I show the Message boxes?

What can I do to switch back and forth between UI thread and Background thread in the following example?

EDIT: This is a piece of code that I want to run on the UI thread:

```
  errorWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.File_Not_Found;
  dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, errorWindow);
  break;
```

If I do something like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    errorWindow.Message = LanguageResources.Resource.File_Not_Found;
    dialogService.ShowDialog(LanguageResources.Resource.Error, errorWindow);
    break;
}
);
```

I get these error messages:

```
Control cannot leave the body of an anonymous method or lambda expression (for break;)

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type
```

I'm using break to break out of the loop, should I just move around my logic to avoid using break or is there a way that I can still use break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke methods.

MSDN link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You could do something like :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MessageBox.Show("some message to display")));
```

---

> Control cannot leave the body of an anonymous method or lambda
>   expression (for break;)

The break needs to be outside the Dispatcher call.
You can do :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
break;
```

---

Just so others can see:

As discussed in chat, you need to get the dispatcher from the UI thread then pass it to your task.

Example:

```
private void DoSomethingAsync() {
    /* here we are on the UI thread */
    Dispatcher dispatcher = (Application.Current!=null) ?
         Application.Current.Dispatcher :
         Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
             /* here we are on the background thread */ 
             PerformCDDetection(dispatcher); 
         }).ContinueWith(t => { ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed; });
}
```

You would need to do the same with Manish's class:

```
private void DoSomethingAsync() {
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

    ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { PerformCDDetection(messageService); }).ContinueWith(t => { ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed; });
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt be Dispatcher.Invoke() for a immediate trapping here?

Comment: @Claw it depends on what the OP wants to do, that's why I mentioned both

Comment: @KalaJ Yes. You can use Invoke to block your background thread there (like Claw mentionned) or you can use BeginInvoke to have it run asynchronously.

Comment: Hm, which method would be better? I think in my case it would not matter but I think I'll have it run asynchronously first and see how that works. Is there a difference performance wise?

Comment: Hi, I'm going to update my question. I'm running into two errors. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing, getting:An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58497/discussion-between-kala-j-and-kugans).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reusable MessageService that could be accessed or invoked from any part of your application.

Something like this:

Note: This code assumes that MessageService instance is created on a UI thread. Which is generally the case if you inject this instance to your container inside BootStrapper. Or else, would work even if you instantiate from inside any .xaml.cs code.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Could be injected to your UnityContainer as singleton and then accessed by using Container.Resolve
        /// </summary>

    public interface IMessageService
    {
        void ShowDialog(string message, MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton);
    }

    public class MessageService : IMessageService
    {
        private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        public MessageService()
        {
          if(Application.Current!=null){
             _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
          }
          else{
            _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
          }
        }

        public void ShowDialog(string message, MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton)
        {
            if (_dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Show(message, messageBoxButton);
            }
            else
            {
                _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Show(message, messageBoxButton)));
            }
        }

        private static void Show(string message, MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, message, "TITLE", messageBoxButton);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: If not using any unity container, you can simply instantiate MessageService from inside your code. Like inside "DoSomethingAsync" in your case.

Comment: Pardon me. I'm not sure what you mean by , "inject this instance to your container inside BootStrapper."? I haven't worked with Singletons yet. Right now, the dialogs I want to pop up are custom dialogs if that helps in anyway.

Comment: EDIT: I'm not using Unity for WPF. Do I need to use Unity for this?

Comment: Thanks Manish, I used part of your code to get it working. I had to use a combination of your answer and kugans. Both of you really deserve an answer mark but I gave it an upvote.